# Removing item from a list based on property

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an odd situation where the line of code takes more than 5 minutes to execute, and I cannot understand why:

```
var cleansedTransactions = competitorTransactions.Where(i => !endedItemsLocal.Contains(i.ItemID)).ToList();
```

To explain further:

```
competitorTransactions - is a list of transactions which in this case contains 921 record inside it;

endedItemsLocal - is an IEnumerable<string> - which in this case contains 8 records
```

What I'm trying to do here is to remove all items that are contained in "endedItemsLocal" (IEnumerable) from "competitorTransactions" list.

Why is it taking 5-9 minutes to execute ? I would be okay to say it takes 9 minutes if these two collections contained millions of records, but only 921 and 8, it's driving me crazy here, and I cannot understand why it takes this long ? Can someone help me out ? :/

Comment: store `endedItemsLocal` in a `List<T>`, you iterating over it 921 times.

Comment: @vasily.sib yes that occurred to me now.. I will try it ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not work with IEnumerable since it is lazy loaded. Use ToArray of endedItemsLocal and work with that collection, that will allocate a collection and thereby boost the speed.

Comment: Hamit , .ToList or ToArray ? Which one is more efficient ? :)

Comment: `List<T>` uses `T[]` internally, so it is almost the same

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with collection, if you want to add some more items to it later then it is a good idea to have it as a list, otherwise vasily.sib is right about the behavior.